# How to: Google Feed API contentSnippet remove readmore text

Tags: google-feed-api

I've searching but i cant find a solution for this..
Is there any way to remove the "read more" text from contentSnippet?

Cheers, 
Jun

Answer (score 0):

In the entries[] there are two sections,  contentSnippet and content.

content - The body of this entry, inlcuding HTML tags. Since this value can contain HTML tags, you should display this value usingelem.innerHTML = entry.content (as opposed to using document.createTextNode). Corresponds to the  or elements in Atom and the  element in RSS.

contentSnippet - A snippet (< 120 characters) version of the content attribute. The snippet does not contain any HTML tags.

So I guess if you used the data from content then you want get the 'read more' of the contentSnippet.

Comment: yeah i got that, what i mean is, can we customize the contentSnippet? my problem is, in my contentSnippet   i can see that there is a "… Read More " included, i really want to get rid of that text because its no use since there's no anchor tag and i already had a custom readmore link.

Comment: Which language are your using to process the feed, couldn't you do some string editing on the snippet?